# How can I set up a triple-monitor panoramic view?

Tags: monitor, flight-simulator-x

My three monitors have varying resolutions if that matters.

Comment: You will need to give us a little more information. What motherboard, and graphics cards do you have?

Answer (score 1):

To have multiple monitors working with Flight Simulator X, you need a Video Card that allows you to hook up those monitors. If that is the case, [configure them correctly](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/set-up-multiple-monitors) via the control panel of Windows.

After that is all working, proceed with these Steps:

- Start Flight Simulator X.
- Click Learning Center.
- Click the Index tab, and then click the letter D to go to the Display section.
- Under Display, click Using Multiple Monitors.

Next, open the folder "%AppData%\Microsoft\FSX-SE" by pasting this path into your local explorer. Then open the file fsx_se.cfg with any text editor of your choice. Look for `WideViewAspect=false` and change it to `WideViewAspect=true`.

After doing that, you should be able to set a resolution that works with your setup in the options of FSX. However, I am note quite sure if this works with monitors with different resolutions. I assume this will only work correctly if you have 3 feature identical monitors.

Comment: As mentioned you will need at least 1 graphics card that supports this.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful in getting things set up.  I already had my three monitors set up, of course, so no issues on the hardware front. :)  The information in the Learning Center helped significantly, though it was a little incomplete for a beginner like myself (it wasn't obvious to me how to pan a view, for example, but I found it through a little experimentation: holding space while moving the mouse).  The varying resolutions didn't end up being an issue, but I'm using windowed mode right now, so I can't confirm whether any of this works in full-screen mode.

Comment: @Josh1billion If it was helpful and solved your issue, you should mark it as answer, so the question is higher rated in searches.